# QTP/UFT - Include A Select All Text in SendKeys Function

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, uft14

So I have this send keys function:

*Code:*

```
Public Function sendKeys(Obj, strParam)
    Wait(1)
    Obj.Click
    Dim shell
    Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    shell.SendKeys strParam
    set shell = Nothing
    Wait(2)
End Function
```

But what I would like to do is include in this function a way to first select the text in the **WebEdit** field then enter the data.

At the moment what I do is this:

*Code:*

```
call sendKeys( Browser("openurl:= ").Page("url:= ").WebElement("xpath:= "), "^a")
call sendKeys( Browser("openurl:= ").Page("url:= ").WebElement("xpath:= "), "text")
```

So essentially what I would like to do is combine the above into one statement that performs the select all text and inserts the required text.

Comment: If the field is a `WebEdit`, just use the `.Set` method of the `webedit` which will do essentially what you require in that it will clear the value and set it to whatever you want it to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, just add a line to your sendkeys function :

```
Public Function sendKeys(Obj, strParam)
    Wait(1)
    Obj.Click
    Dim shell
    Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    shell.SendKeys "^a" 'New line
    shell.SendKeys strParam
    set shell = Nothing
    Wait(2) 
End Function
```